# How to get a pixel color in J2ME?

Tags: java-me, colors, pixel

I have drawn a canvas and i want to know how to get a pixel color of the canvas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Create a mutable `Image`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Image.html#createImage%28int,%20int%29) the same size as your `Canvas`.  Then, any operations you perform on your Canvas's `Graphics` object, perform the same ones on your Image's [Graphics](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Image.html#getGraphics%28%29) object.

Finally, get the pixel data from the Image using [`getRGB()`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Image.html#getRGB%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29); it should be the same as the Canvas.

Comment: Thank you , would you give me an example ?

Comment: Hm.  I thought my description was quite clear...  I have linked to the necessary method and class documentation, so it should be very straightforward to do this.  What bit are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't. `Graphics` class, which is used to draw to `Canvas`, is for painitng only, it can't give you any information on the pixels.

Comment: What about the converting the canvas to an image ?

Comment: What do you mean by converting the canvas? `Canvas` is a class, which you extend to perform drawing operations. You have `Graphics` object though, but you can't convert it to anything or get information about already drawn pixels. No, the only solution without using any other APIs is the one funkybro has suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting a platform that supports the NokiaUI API you can use the [DirectGraphics#getPixels](http://library.forum.nokia.com/topic/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-237420DE-CCBE-4A74-A129-572E0708D428/com/nokia/mid/ui/DirectGraphics.html) to read pixel data. On mobile platforms with graphics accelerator hardware, reading pixels tend to be slower so you should use this very sparingly.

Comment: Nokia UI API is supported by SE phones since JP-3 (that's K700, S700, K500...)